# How to retrieve logical expressions (KO based) for reactions from KEGG?

Tags: kegg, database, data-retrieval

The completeness of a module can easily be checked by looking at the `Definition` entry associated with the module. For example, in module [M00010](http://www.genome.jp/kegg-bin/show_module?M00010), it is given as:

```
Definition  K01647 (K01681,K01682) (K00031,K00030)
```

which can be translated to:

```
K01647 AND (K01681 OR K01682) AND (K00031 OR K00030)
```

If this expression evaluates to `TRUE`, the module is considered complete.

I am wondering whether analogous information exists for a single *reaction*. For example, when looking at reaction [R00352](http://www.genome.jp/dbget-bin/www_bget?rn:R00352), one finds the following information about its Orthology:

[image]

But I can't easily find the logical relation that correspond to the KOs for this reaction. It could be:

```
K01648 AND K15230 AND K15231
```

or:

```
K01648 OR K15230 OR K15231
```

or:

```
K01648 OR (K15230 AND K15231)
```

and so on.

In the above example, I know that the correct expression is:

```
K01648 OR (K15230 AND K15231)
```

i.e. one either needs either `K01648` or both of the other two subunits.

Can this information be retrieved from KEGG for each reaction and if so, how?

Comment: Have you tried to asked KEGG directly via http://www.kegg.jp/feedback/ ? If anything, that might give them the information that there's something missing which people need.

Comment: You might need to look into the FTP dump; I looked into the KEGG REST API (http://www.kegg.jp/kegg/rest/keggapi.html) and couldn't find anything related to your question...

Answer (score 1):

Some information seems to be available on the module level utilising the API.

Reaction [R00352](http://www.genome.jp/dbget-bin/www_bget?rn:R00352) points to the module [M00173](https://www.genome.jp/kegg-bin/show_module?M00173). While some information is in the `Definition`, it's not trivial to link it to the particular reaction. This linkage is however easier accessible via [API](http://rest.kegg.jp/get/md:M00173):

[image: Reaction orthology defined on module level]

Comment: Thanks. There are two issues with this as far as I can see: i) the third KO (K01648) is missing in the list and ii) it is not clear which logical relationship exists between these KOs; it seems it is always an AND but it is not entirely clear (e.g. from the link you provide: `K00239,K00240,K00241,K00242,K00244,K00245,K00246,K00247` - do I need all of these or not?.

Comment: This table seems to point where the indicated members should all be required as one. In a couple of cases I looked it is indeed the case. Hence ad i) K01648 is separate so should not be noted ad ii) a very detailed decomposition to subunits, but yes.